# Does setting TCP_NODELAY disable auto-corking?

Tags: linux, networking, system-programming

Does setting TCP_NODELAY turn off the auto corking behavior? Is there a way to disable it on a per connection basis?

Comment: Originally asked on SO, but it was immediately voted down. Maybe because it was Linux specific?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124098/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-tcp-cork-and-tcp-nodelay-in-this-use

Comment: @MC68020 That's for explicit TCP_CORK not for autocorking that applies even when TCP_CORK isn't specified.